# Genymotion and virtualbox dependency

Tags: android, virtual-machine, virtualbox, genymotion

Why should we install virtualbox when we are using Genymotion, and one thing else, when we are downloading devices in Genymtion, suppose our system crashes, will we get back those devices, that we had already downloaded

any idea

Comment: Genymotion runs on virtual box and if you have googled it then genymotion has quite some awesome features when it comes to android emulator's. System crashes doesn't ensures anything. You can always download them again.

Answer (score 0):

Genymotion works as a virtual machine, therefore requires a virtualization software.
They could make their own software, but that probably seemed to be unpractical and unnecessary, since VirtualBox is good at its job, and is free.

The devices you have already downloaded will be preserved. If your system crashes while it's being downloaded, you'll need to download it again.